# Gstreamer: Unable to finalize video recorded in parallel to streaming via gst-rtsp-server

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, matroska

I'm developing a Gstreamer (v1.14.4) application where I serve a live video stream over RTSP and alongside record it on-device with a different bitrate. To serve the RTSP stream, I use gst-rtsp-server. In order to both stream and record, I have a `tee` and a `proxysink` in the lauch line I give to the RTSP server and a second pipeline with a `proxysrc` and a `filesink`:

RTPS pipeline:

```
v4l2src --> tee  --> proxysink
                 |--> queue --> omxh264enc --> h264parse --> rtph264pay pt=96 name=pay0
```

Recording pipeline:

```
proxysrc --> omxh264enc --> h264parse --> matroskamux --> filesink
```

When a client connects, I link the two proxy elements in the RTSP media factory's `"media-configure"` callback. Both streaming and writing to file works, except that the file is not seekable, I assume because it's not properly finalized.

I am trying to finalize it when I get a `"teardown-request"` from the `GstRTSPClient` by calling the following function (`CustomData` is a struct holding pointers to all the Gstreamer elements I need.):

```
void stop_recording(CustomData *data)
{
  if (data == NULL) {
    GST_ERROR("Got NULL CustomData!");
    return;
  }

  if (data->record_writer != NULL) { // record_writer is the filesink element
    GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->record_writer, "sink");
    if (sink_pad == NULL) {
      g_print("sink pad is null");
      return;
    }

    int send_eos = gst_pad_send_event(sink_pad, gst_event_new_eos());

    // DEBUG: check that the EOS reaches the end of the pipeline
    GstBus *bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(data->record_pipeline));
    GstMessage *msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_EOS);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg) == GST_MESSAGE_EOS) {
      g_print("got EOS on bus\n");
    } else {
      g_print("got something else on bus %d\n", GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg));
    }

    gst_message_unref(msg);

  } else {
    g_print("Can't stop recording, record_pipeline not initialized\n");
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected here and "got EOS on bus" is printed. However, the file is not seekable.
Besides what's shown in the above function I have tried:

- sending the EOS not to the sinkpad of the filesink, but to the filesink element itself. Then I do not get the message on the bus (`gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered` hangs indefinitely)
- sending the EOS not to the filesink, but to the whole record pipeline. Again, no EOS on the bus.
- trying all of the above just after ensuring the record pipeline is in the playing state. That makes no difference.

I've successfully written to properly finalized video files before, but never in conjunction with gst-rtsp-streamer. I suspect the issue lies there, maybe because the recording pipeline is not getting new data from the streaming pipeline at the time when I try to finalize the recording.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `filesink` is just a disk writer. It is pretty dump. Setting that one to EOS will not fix anything. Sounds to me you want the `matroskamux` to be set EOS so it can do proper finalization.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried sending the EOS to the entire record pipeline (starting at `proxysrc`), but then the signal does not appear to be propagating down the pipeline (I never see it on the bus). Why could that be?

Comment: Not sure tbh. Maybe after EOS has been sent proxysrc receives another frame, which may it find unexpected and errors out before the EOS can find it's way down?

Comment: @Nicolas I'm having the same issue as you with a similar structure. I can stop a single pipeline and finalize with an EOS, but I can't get it to work with proxysrc/sinks. Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I looked into it... it's possible to get a clean shutdown if you are looking to terminate all pipelines at once, but if you are looking to shutdown the proxysrc pipeline while keeping the sending pipeline running, EOS directly to the pipeline will not work. Florian pointed out that sending directly an EOS to the muxer does the job, although not pretty, it works.